# Using VSCode in a layered container-virtual machine setup

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote

I have a local vscode setup which uses 'remote connection' to ubuntu (multipass) as described [here](https://ubuntu.com/blog/how-to-create-a-vscode-linux-remote-environment). On that ubuntu machine I have a docker container running with some rust code to be worked on.

I'm having trouble getting a good setup for rust-analyzer and clippy etc. as the docs I find describe the setup of running this container from your host, not from multipass etc. So my setup is 'one layer deeper'. Can this be done using VScode and how?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions in the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/develop-remote-host#_connect-using-the-remote-ssh-extension-recommended) as if working within a container on a remote host and use the "Connect using the Remote - SSH extension (recommended)" solution. Only difference is that your 'remote host' is now running locally, but for the config not really matters.

As decribed in these docs above you need also to take care of proper ssh key forwarding. Then it just works, meaning the running container on my multipass  ubuntu will show up so you can work in it with VScode (and install VScode extensions in it etc.).